# Assigning an empty list makes it bool?

Tags: python, types, variable-assignment

Up to now I thought that lists can hold element of different types and that each element has its own type information. However, this example seems to suggest something different:

```
def not_working():
    A = B = []
    for x in range(1,30):
        A.append("str")
        B.append(True)
    for a,b in zip(A,B):
        print a + str(b)
```

This result in an error

```
print a + str(b)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'bool' and 'str'
```

While this works as expected:

```
def working():
    A = []
    B = []
    for x in range(1,30):
        A.append("str")
        B.append(True)
    for a,b in zip(A,B):
        print a + str(b)
```

Note that the only difference is `A = B = []` vs `A = []` and `B = []` in seperate lines.

Why is the first function broken while the second one works as expected?

Comment: To note: `A = B = []` is an empty list (the same list for both) referred to by two names.... `A = []` and `B = []` are two empty lists with two different names... So your appending in the first... is going to append both str and True to the same list (you're then zipping that one big list to itself effectively - every second element of A (and B) is going to be `True` the boolean value...)... try printing out `A` and `B` and look at how they differ...

Comment: _A little note evolves into a detailed answer._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, `A` and `B`refer to the same list so each time you call append, both are changed.

```
a = b = []

a.append("str")
print(a, b) # ['str'] ['str']

b.append(True)
print(a, b) # ['str', True] ['str', True]
```

When you call the `zip` function, you obtain the list `[("str", "str"), (True, True)]`, instead of the expected `[("str", True)]`.

You then try to `print True + str(True)` wich is why you get the `TypeError`.

In the second case, the list are different:

```
c = []
d = []
c.append("str") 
print(c, d) # ['str'] []

d.append(True)
print(c, d) # ['str'] [True]
```

Answer (score 3):

So when you do `A = B = []` this is defining a single list referenced by the variables `A` and `B`.

You can check this with the following code

```
A = B = []
A.append('a')
print(A)
print(B)
```

You will notice that both `A` and `B` will be `['a']`

The error then occurs because the a variable can be a boolean in the final loop

Comment: ups, I knew that either my expectations or python is broken (with a strong tendency towards the first ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
def not_working():
    A = B = []
    for x in range(1, 5):
        A.append("str")
        B.append(True)
    print("A:", A, "B: ", B)

def working():
    A = []
    B = []
    for x in range(1, 5):
        A.append("str")
        B.append(True)
    print("A:", A, "B: ", B)

not_working()
working()

A: ['str', True, 'str', True, 'str', True, 'str', True]
B:  ['str', True, 'str', True, 'str', True, 'str', True]
A: ['str', 'str', 'str', 'str']
B:  [True, True, True, True]
```

There fore in your first attempt you will be trying to add `True + "str"` which will give your error but your second attempt will do `str(True) + "str"` which will work.